# flex textarea text attribute but still renders as html

Tags: apache-flex, text, textarea, image

actually i got to the cause of the issue.

if you feed the textarea text attribute with an  tag that has a valid src url, then for some reason flex will try to render everything as html.

Eg, try this:

```
<mx:TextArea id="textArea" width="100%" height="90%" text="<img src='http://url-to-a-valid-img"/>
```

and instead of it rendering it as raw text it will render it as an html.

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, strange i manage to fix this issue. its a weird fix not sure why I had to do it.

But basically, when i copy over the variable's string content into a TextArea htmlText - any img with a valid src seems to get erased.

Its an odd issue that I just want to move on from.

Answer (score 0):

Really?  I cannot even get it to compile with the **<** symbol there.  Have you tried converting using &lt;?

Comment: flex will try to load the src of the img. I can't convert encode the angle brackets because I am letting the user edit the content. so:

<img src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" />

must still show up as like that and not encoded on the TextArea control.

Comment: by the way, i also tried what you did, you are right, flex doesn't let you compile, but the content comes from a variable so i just assign it to the text area during run time.